# Are there any terms for the summer directly after high/secondary school?

Tags: slang

Leaving school seems like such a huge event in our lives. There's this single summer where you have more freedom than you've ever had before with a group of people you've grown up with before you all go off in different directions in life: work, uni, travel, whatever. It might be the last chance to spend time with these people before you ever see them again, and so people want to make the most of this time, moreso than other summer breaks. It therefore seems strange to me that I've never heard that summer be given a special name, even in slang.

Whether it's a formal term, colloquialism, slang, or TikTok hashtag, has anyone ever heard **a name for this liminal period straight after compulsory education**?

Comment: The summer after high-school graduation. There is no specific word for that.

Comment: I agree there's probably no common word for this, but the OP will also accept slang and colloquial terms, which might exist within smaller groups.

Comment: You're right that it's a pretty significant time and deserves a name, but I can't think of any specific word or phrase for it.

Comment: Broadly no. Where are you asking from, though? I can't see it but there might be differences among British, US American and other forms of English.

Comment: I'm asking from the UK and a preferred answer would be British English, but would be curious about a term in any dialect.